# Netty XML-RPC library

Tags: java, netty

I am about to work on a project whereby the protocol involved is the XML-RPC. I would like to know how best I can write an XML-RPC library with netty. The reasons behind the idea is that I would like to handle asysnchronous requests with low resource consumption. Yes I have discovered the Apache Xml-Rpc library. However I do not really know whether it can help in the asynchronous way.

Any ideas will be a good help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can reuse the Apache Xml-Rpc library and when you call setTransportFactory define a new TransportFactory implementation that uses netty. The library already comes with several implementations so adding a netty impl should be the easiest way.

Comment: Please can you give any good link or tutorial on how to implement custom transport?